# Why is Ubuntu booting very slowly?

Tags: boot, startup, time, bootchart

I haven't used Ubuntu in some time, but as I booted it up again several minutes ago it took nearly 2 minutes to reach the login screen. I installed bootchart after that and did another reboot, and although Ubuntu booted up somewhat faster, I still would like someone to investigate this matter by looking at my bootchart below. Can anyone tell me what is going on?

[image: Bootchart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a VFAT check on your boot that is taking 10s before file systems can be mounted.  To get rid of these 10 seconds use one of the following two solutions:

1. If the VFAT partition is a removable disk, attach it to a Windows machine and run a `chkdsk  /f` on that drive under Windows
2. If you don't have a Windows machine, download [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/), install it on a USB stick and boot with that and then run the `chkdsk /f` from the DOS command line.

Only if those solutions do not work should you:

- copy all data to another disk and reformat and copy back.

Your network resolving seems to be slow: check your network and/or DNS server as well.

Comment: Thanks Fabby for your response. If I understand correctly, you suggest that I format my disk (HDD) to prevent a VFAT check from occurring. As doing this and reinstalling my operating systems would be a time-consuming task, is there a way to prevent VFAT checks from running at boot? Also, you mentioned slow network resolving. What, more specifically, can I do to remedy this issue?

Comment: No, that's not what I said.  see updated answer.  ;-)

Comment: @user311982: Don't thank me!  **;-)** If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!

Comment: Wow this was quite a while ago! I haven't had any slowness issues lately.  Could be due to me clean installing newer versions of Ubuntu as they came out, so 15.04 and now, 15.10, which boots really fast! Unfortunately, I wasn't able to figure out the problem, but I appreciated your time and efforts to help me. I'll mark your response as the answer

Comment: And I'll return the favour!  @user311982!  **;-)**